# Send a slack message on Luigi job failure

Tags: luigi

What's the best way to have any [Luigi](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) task failure post a message to slack? I know tasks have an overridable on_failure method, but is there any way to specify a global policy instead of per-task?

My current approach is that I have a SlackOnFailureMixin (pasted below) that overrides the on_failure method, but I have to manually mix it in to every `luigi.Task` that I want to have this functionality in, and if I forget then the failures aren't posted.

This is the source for my SlackOnFailure mixin in case anyone is curious as to this approach.

```py
class SlackOnFailureMixin:
    """
    IMPORTANT NOTE! Make sure this mixin goes first in your class list, i.e.

        class MyTask(SlackOnFailureMixin, luigi.Task):

    Due to Python's method resolution order (MRO), this won't work unless you
    mix it in first.
    """

    def on_failure(self, exception):
        message = super().on_failure(exception)
        if "SLACK_ON_FAILURE" in os.environ:
            slack.eng_errors.post_error_message(
                f"Error in Luigi Task: {self.task_id}", message
            )
        return message
```

Can anyone recommend a better way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can always just create a base class that you inherit from that extends Luigi to what you need.

```py
class BaseTask(luigi.Task):
    def on_failure(self, exception):
        message = super().on_failure(exception)
        if "SLACK_ON_FAILURE" in os.environ:
            slack.eng_errors.post_error_message(
                f"Error in Luigi Task: {self.task_id}", message
            )
        return message
```

That's pretty much the only (and best) way to do this. You actually don't need to change any of your mixin's code, just put it into a base class instead.